# Mysql Query [0001]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL and I'm trying to get the number of owners who own at least one dog, for each city. My tables are:

```
owners
  id, name, city
```

and

```
dogs
  id, owner_id, name, weight
```

I have the following so far:

```
SELECT owners.city, count(dogs.id) AS 'Owners' 
FROM owners INNER JOIN dogs ON (owners.id = dogs.owner_id) 
GROUP BY owners.city
```

However, this gives me the total number of dogs per city. But I'd like to get the number of dog owners per city.

How should I do this?

Comment: The SQL concepts you're going to want to use to complete this: JOIN, COUNT and GROUP BY.  If you need further help I'd suggest you edit your post showing us what you have so far.

Comment: What is the relation between these table? owner id or dog id are same! id field ambiguous here.

Comment: Thanks in advance for what? You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I've added my progress. Any chance for help now? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count only owners id with DISTINCT word, which counts only unique owners.

```
SELECT owners.city, count(DISTINCT owners.id) AS 'Owners' 
FROM owners INNER JOIN dogs ON (owners.id = dogs.owner_id) 
GROUP BY owners.city
```

Comment: :) In SQL you need to think in the way "what you want to get" not "how you want to get it" mostly... this is why it is called Query language. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The information you have given does not allow for a precise answer. There are two separate tables, each having attributes that describe the things (dogs, owners), but the tables are disjoint.

I'd suggest adding a "owner_id" column to the "dogs" table. Then you can select from owners, group by city, et cetera.

After you have updated the question, solved this for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/403f7/4/0