# Mysql Query [0002]

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I got two Mysql tables and I'm having a hard time doing following query.

Query: Get the the sales value per month, per city

**users**
*id, name, city*

**sales**
*id, user_id, name, amount, date (datetime)*

I started with `SELECT MONTHNAME(datetime) AS month GROUP BY month.`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free SQL course, referring to your [previous topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478330/mysql-query-0001).

Comment: My my niels... how about answering questions instead of questioning questions?!

Comment: No problem, as long as I get an advance payment. I'm not here to do your job writing basic SQL, I'm here to solve interesting problems that are worth solving. You are not even asking a question, you're just dumping your problem here and waiting for an answer.

Comment: Ouch, that's a lot of ego.

Comment: use inner join between the two tables and then group by on required fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a figure of 0 for any month and / or city which doesn't have any sales, but where there are sales for other cities for that month then something like this:-

Cross join a pair of subselects, one to get a list of the months used and one to get a list of the cities, then join those against the records to get the amounts for that month / city, and sum those amounts up:-

```
SELECT Sub1.YearMonth, Sub2.city, SUM(sales.amount)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) AS YearMonth
FROM sales) Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT city FROM users) Sub2
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON Sub1.YearMonth = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM sales.`date`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON sales.user_id = users.id AND Sub2.city = sales.city
GROUP BY Sub1.YearMonth, Sub2.city
ORDER BY Sub1.YearMonth, Sub2.city
```

Down side of this is that if you have a month where nothing was sold to anybody then this month will not appear at all. To get around this you would need to change the subselect for the months to instead take a start date and add a range of numbers to it to get each month.

An example of generating a range is as follows:-

```
SELECT Sub1.YearMonth, Sub2.city, SUM(sales.amount)
FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE_ADD('2009-01-01', INTERVAL a.i*100+b.i*10+c.i MONTH)) AS aMonth
FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c
WHERE DATE_ADD('2009-01-01', INTERVAL a.i*100+b.i*10+c.i MONTH) <=  '2014-12-01') Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT city FROM users) Sub2
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON Sub1.YearMonth = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM sales.`date`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON sales.user_id = users.id AND Sub2.city = sales.city
GROUP BY Sub1.YearMonth, Sub2.city
ORDER BY Sub1.YearMonth, Sub2.city
```

This example is giving every month between 2009-01-01 and 2014-12-01 inclusive, then getting all the sales by city for that range. It will cope with a range of up to 1000 months.

Answer (score 1):

Hey noob (nice name btw) :D

Try this one, I've added the `YEAR()` on the `GROUP BY` clause since month numbers are repeating per year, and I suppose you do not want the sum of sales of records with the same month but different in year. You can just omit the year on the `SELECT` statement if you do not want it.

```
SELECT YEAR(S.date) AS Year
    , MONTHNAME(S.date) AS Month
    , U.city
    , SUM(S.amount) AS SalesPerMonthPerCity
    FROM sales S
    INNER JOIN users U ON U.id = S.user_id
    GROUP BY YEAR(S.date), MONTH(S.date), U.city
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an [SQL Fiddle test page](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/198bf/1) so you and others can try the solution.

This is the query in question:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(`date`) AS Monthly
     , `city`
     , SUM(`amount`) AS Profit
FROM sales
INNER JOIN users ON userid = idu
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(`date`), `city` WITH ROLLUP
```

Used the `WITH ROLLUP` to add a subtotal by month and a grand total at the end.

PS: I agree with the comments, you should show some more effort on solving your problem, you are not new on SO so you should be aware of that ;)